# cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'hdp:configuration'

Tags: java, spring, hadoop, spring-boot

Getting following Error for Spring Yarn Application.
But Every things seems to be well placed like XSD and EVerything

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop/spring-hadoop.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaWarning(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:510) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.xx.poc.Application.main(Application.java:88) [bin/:na]

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 14 in XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 14; columnNumber: 21; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'hdp:configuration'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:510)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.xx.poc.Application.main(Application.java:88)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 14; columnNumber: 21; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'hdp:configuration'.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at
```

Here is my ApplicationContext.xml.
No fire wall issues nothing it works fine if we remove those hdp tags.
Also worked with different options like putting xsd to classpath etx.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:hdp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop" xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop/spring-hadoop.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.2.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />
    <hdp:configuration>
        fs.defaultFS=${fs.default.name}
        mapred.job.tracker=${mapred.job.tracker}
    </hdp:configuration>

    <hdp:job id="wordCountJobId" input-path="${input.path}"
        output-path="${output.path}" jar-by-class="com.xx.yy.Application"
        mapper="com.xx.yy.Map" reducer="com.xx.yy.Reduce" />

    <hdp:job-runner id="wordCountJobRunner" job-ref="wordCountJobId"
        run-at-startup="true" />
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the schema from your classpath - the XSD is in [the namespace sub-project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop/tree/master/spring-hadoop-namespace) and gets bundled into the spring-data-hadoop jar.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-hadoop</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

works fine for me.

Comment: I do have all the required jars in the classpath and even i tried putting xsd into classpath

Comment: That must not be the case; Spring maps the schema url to a physical file using the [spring-schemas](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop/blob/master/spring-hadoop-namespace/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.schemas) file in the jar.

Comment: Seems like i have spring-hadoop.jar but couldnt find spring-hadoop-namespace.jar as subproject.So ho can i add that jar to my project i couldnt find same as different jar

Comment: For me; the XSD is in the main jar - what version are you using? I just added the version from the [project page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-hadoop/) to my POM and the schema is in the jar.